# Simple UIPickerView Error

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I get the following error on the line with `myPicker.dataSource = self`. Does anyone know why this is or what I can do to fix it?

> Threat 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var textFIled: UITextField!

    let pickerData = ["Mozzarella","Gorgonzola","Provolone","Brie","Maytag Blue","Sharp Cheddar","Monterrey Jack","Stilton","Gouda","Goat Cheese", "Asiago"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myPicker.dataSource = self
        myPicker.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textFIled.text = pickerData[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens when your `IBOulet` is not right connected to the UIPickerView in the story board. Delete all connections and connect again.

Comment: Beat you to it by 2 secs ;)

Comment: Alright. How do you connect the IBOutlet? I tried hitting control and then dragging it into the code but it won't let me drop it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `myPickerView` is connected in the storyboard. Check whether the outlet names are the same in the storyboard and the `ViewController`.

If no luck, try connecting your storyboard `UIPickerView` to the delegate and datasource through the storyboard. Right click and drag from the picker view to the view controller and select "delegate" and "dataSource".